# Is this possible? ee5 / tab / custom view

Tags: entry, publish-layout, entryid

Before i dive in too deep, i just wanted to ask the community here if what i'm trying to achieve is possible.

Essentially, i want to create a tab on the entry PUBLISH page let's call it Extra. Then i want to take complete ownership of the contents of that tab and place a bunch of php code in there for some non-EE related functionality. I simply need to do this within a publish tab in EE to grab the entry_id while a user is editing it. I did this in EE2 via Accessories, but those have been deprecated since and i'm assuming this is an option.

Is this doable? OR can you suggest a way of doing this another way?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. If you create a module, you can set up a tab file that allows you to do what you want:

https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/development/modules.html#the-tab-file-tabmodule_namephp

Comment: Yea i saw this when i was readin add-on dev doc. But it seems to me like this tab.module_name.php file only expects a returned array of data. I need to place a "view" like page into it.

Comment: It seems to me like i'll need to make use of the view service, but not certain yet. https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/development/services/view.html